# sudoing my own bash scripting

Tags: bash, scripts, sudo, root

Okay, so I have my scripts in ~/bin/, and they are added to the path normally. However, when I prefix them with sudo, they are not in the path. I figure this is because they're not in the path for root which sudo is using.

How can I change it so sudo also looks in my path? Or alternatively, so that my bin is in the root path? Thanks!

Comment: it can be a security flaw tho, as a non root user can remove or edit such scripts (such user can be someone else with your normal user or "anyone" without your password in the same group with write access to your script files); my suggestion is to create them at `/MyScripts`, make it and all the scripts there like: `root:root rw-r--r--`; another problem I just thought is if you have them synched with a remote storage and it gets changed there and downloaded to your local machine.

Answer (score 3):

Open a terminal:

```
sudo visudo
```

Edit the line like so (and change wojox to your user):

```
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/home/wojox/bin"
```

Comment: I removed the extra colon after the user's bin entry in path, as this actually meant that the current working directory was in path as well, and this you do not want.